# Argument 1 passed to __construct must be an instance of Services\ProductManager, none given

Tags: php, symfony, twig

in service.yml

```
test_product.controller:
        class: MyBundle\Controller\Test\ProductController
        arguments: ["@product_manager.service"]
```

in controller

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
     /**
     * @var ProductManager
     */
    private $productManager;

    public function __construct(ProductManager $productManager){
        $this->productManager = $productManager;
    }
}
```

in routing.yml

```
test_product_addNew:
    path: /test/product/addNew
    defaults: { _controller:test_product.controller:addNewAction }
```

I want to use ProductManger in contructor to do some stuff but it gives me this error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   MyBundle\Controller\Test\ProductController::__construct()
>   must be an instance of MyBundle\Services\ProductManager,
>   instance of Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Debug\TimedTwigEngine given,
>   called in
>   ..../app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php
>   on line 1202 and defined

I am new to symfony, any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you registered the `ProductManager` as a service? You can access any service in a `Controller` with `$this->get('service_name')`. So no need to inject it.

Comment: He is defining the controller as a service so $this->get is irrelevant.  With the posted code I don't see how the twig engine is being injected instead of the product manager service.  I'm guessing he has edited the wrong file.

Answer (score 1):

You have inverted the logical of services.

First, it's your manager wich must be defined as a service because it's it you will need to call from controller.

```
// services.yml
product_manager:
        class: MyBundle\Path\To\ProductManager
```

Then call directly your manager defined as a service in your controller.

```
// Controller
class ProductController extends Controller
{
     [...]
     $this->get('product_manager');
     [...]
}
```

And you do not need to overload __construct() methode. Only call `->get(any_service)` where you need it.

Also your route is wrong. You have to define controller from is namespace.

```
// routing.yml
test_product_addNew:
    path: /test/product/addNew
    defaults: { _controller:MyBundle:Product:addNew }
```

Comment: also to mention, overwriting the constructor of a controller is no good practive, if you want to initialize a class variable use `setContainer`

Comment: Unless of course you are defining the controller as a service.  Which is what the op is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Symfony 3.3** (released May 2017) you can use contructor injection and autowiring with ease:

```
# services.yml 
services
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    MyBundle\Controller\Test\ProductController: ~
```

Keep rest as you already had.

Do you want to know more about there features? Check this [post with examples](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/).